# error: Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, razor, url-routing

```
[HttpGet("Verification?g={g}")]
        public IActionResult Verify (string g)
        {
            return View("Verification.cshtml");
        }
```

> I wrote the routing like above but then there was an *error*
> **"Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character."**

> how to write controller routing to create URL like
> **http://localhost/VerificationController/Verify/Verification?g={guid}**

Please help me to solve this, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When any defined parameter not referenced as part of the route rule the MVC parser trying to interpret it as query parameter. Therefore, to get URL like

`https://localhost/VerificationController/Verify/Verification?g=some_value`

you can use:

```cs
[HttpGet("{controller}/Verify/Verification")]
public IActionResult Verify(string g)
{
    return View("Verification.cshtml");
}
```

Or, if you controller class is prefixed with `[Route("[controller]")]` you can use:

```cs
[HttpGet("Verify/Verification")]
public IActionResult Verify(string g)
{
    return View("Verification.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: The first one solved it. Thank you so much.